# Copy and Paste mysql database on same server (easiest and fastest way )

Tags: mysql, database

Now I am going to clone huge database on same server I need to copy and paste mysql db remotely without download huge .sql file.

Are there any GUI tool do that in easy way?

What is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a paid hosting, you are probably running on [phpmyadmin](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/). You can easily port your database using the export and import tabs.

Comment: sorry  yesterday I could not describe  my issue in detail now I have added some explanation ... I found the solution and I will add it now

Comment: I use SQLyog Community tool and I use Copy Database To Different Host/DB just like

https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/Copy_Database_to_Different_Host_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm